# Filter Data in SQL with timestamp

Tags: sql, join, filter, case

I am learning SQL. So i have some tables like this:

[image: price]

[image: contract]

So the product price depends on the time (from and end here).
I have the time ,that the customer order the products.
My question is how can i get the price for each contract.
Could someone here help me . Thank you so much . I wish you a awesome weekend !!

Comment: Complete your example. Contract period could contains more that one price from 1st table. Add price you want to see, in result (2nd table). Or say the contract price will specify from `table2.begin` or `table2.end`?

Comment: your question is not clear. what rdbms are you using? what do you mean by the price for each contract? share the result you're looking to get.

Comment: @safineh thank you for your comment. i want to have the result like: contract 1 with product 1 begin 2017-04-01  to end 2018-03-31 cost 10/ 8 months and 11/3 months.

Comment: @DannySlor i want to have the result like: contract 1 with product 1 begin 2017-04-01  to end 2018-03-31 cost 10/ 8 months and 11/3 months.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BETWEEN` in `INNER JOIN` condition:

```sql
SELECT *, table1.price FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON
    table2.product = table1.product
    AND
    table2.`begin` BETWEEEN table1.`from` AND table2.`end`
```